# Problema ao ordenard div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho 1 problema, estou a usar JS para ordenar DIV'S (funciona corretamente), o probelma ocorre quando clico no botao "editar dessa mesma div", com a imagem torna-se mais fácil preceber.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso eu nao alter a ordem, o botao editar funciona corretamente, caso organize as div pelo "termina em", o botao de editar deixa de funcionar.

Eu reproduzi o problema no JSFIDDLE, pode tentar clicar no botão editar, e vai ver que vai funcionar, depois clique no botão alterar "na barra azul", e o botao editar nao vai mais funcionar.

Alguma dica de como resolver o meu problema?

HTML

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>


<div class="tarefas col-md-12">
<div class="alertas col-md-12"> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="tituloAlertas col-12 col-md-12">
                            <h1 style="color:#333333" class="tituloSessao"> Plano de Trabalhos </h1> 
                        </div>

<div class="col-md-12 row main_alertas">   
                        <div class="col-md-12 blue">
                            <div style="margin:0; padding:0" class="row"> 
                                <div style="width:5%">

                                </div>
                                <div style="width:55.6%">

                                </div>
                                <div style="width:15%">
                                    <button style="margin-left: 5px;background: none; border: none; outline:none" href="#" class="pure-button sorte3"> Alterar</button>
                                    <button style="display:none; margin-left: 5px; background: none; border: none; outline:none" href="#" class="pure-button sorte4"> Alterar</button>  
                                </div>                      
                            </div>   
                        </div> 
                        <div class="col-md-12 sort-list todas-tarefas">
                                    <div data-prioridade="1" data-id="1" data-tempo="-1" class="ordem-trabalhos row">
                                        <div style="width:5%; padding-top:20px; padding-left: 5px;" class="conteudo">

                                        </div>

                                        <div style="width:56.6%;" class="conteudo">
                                            <p class="ticket"><span style="color:#2197D2">#1 </span></p>        
                                        </div>

                                        <div style="width: 30%; padding-top:5px;" class="conteudo">
                                            <span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Termina Em:</b> <br> 
                                                <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #52575D; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;"> Tempo Esgotado </span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>

                                        <div style="width:10%; padding-top: 22px;" class="conteudo col-2 col-md-1">
                                            <a class="btn_tabAlerta edit_alerta" data-title="Atenção!"  title="Editar Tarefas/Alertas" id="editTarefa1">Editar</a>  
                                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-prioridade="2" data-id="2" data-tempo="2" class="ordem-trabalhos row">
                                        <div style="width:5%; padding-top:20px; padding-left: 5px;" class="conteudo">
                                            <i style="color:orange" class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>            
                                        </div>

                                        <div style="width:56.6%;" class="conteudo">
                                            <p class="ticket"><span style="color:#2197D2">#2 </span></p>        
                                        </div>

                                        <div style="width: 30%; padding-top:5px;" class="conteudo">
                                            <span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>Termina Em:</b> <br> 
                                                <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #52575D; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;"> 2 Dias </span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>

                                        <div style="width:10%; padding-top: 22px;" class="conteudo col-2 col-md-1">
                                            <a class="btn_tabAlerta edit_alerta" data-title="Atenção!"  title="Editar Tarefas/Alertas" id="editTarefa2">Editar</a>  
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JS/ Jquerry

```
$("#editTarefa1").on('click', (function(e) {
                                        alert("entrou editar 1");       
                                    }));

                  $("#editTarefa2").on('click', (function(e) {
                                        alert("entrou editar 2");       
                                    }));


              var rooms = $('.ordem-trabalhos');
                            var roomList = $('.sort-list');

                            $( ".sorte3" ).click(function() {
                console.log("entrou");
                                $(".sorte3").hide();
                                $(".sorte4").show();
                                sortAsc();
                            });

                            $( ".sorte4" ).click(function() {
                                $(".sorte4").hide();
                                $(".sorte3").show();
                                sortDesc();
                            });

                            function sortAsc(){
                                roomList.empty();
                                rooms.sort(function(a, b){
                                    return $(a).data('tempo')-$(b).data('tempo')
                                });
                                roomList.append(rooms);
                            }

                            function sortDesc(){
                                roomList.empty();
                                rooms.sort(function(a, b){
                                    return $(b).data('tempo')-$(a).data('tempo')
                                });
                                roomList.append(rooms); 
                            }
```

Link JSFIDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/a8L6hbzx/26/

Comment: É só alterar a forma de capturar o evento. Use `$(document).on('click', "#editTarefa1", (function(e) {` no lugar de `$("#editTarefa1").on('click', (function(e) {`. Está reescrevendo o HTML quando altera a ordem, ou seja, esses novos elementos não estavam no DOM quando vc criou o evento, por isso ele não os escuta.

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou corretamente. ;)